# Copy from CSV and Rename in MS-DOS

Tags: copy-paste, dos, file-rename

I have a .csv file with the following format:

```
<path_including_filename>,<new_filename>
<path_including_filename>,<new_filename>
<path_including_filename>,<new_filename>
<path_including_filename>,<new_filename>
```

I want to copy what's on column #1 in my CSV from Location A to Location B, then rename the file on Location B with the content of the column #2 in my CSV.

This is what I have done so far, the copying works but the renaming seems doesn't really happen:

```
For /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%i in (myCSV.csv) do (copy "%%i" "C:/myFolder" && rename "C:/myFolder/%%~nxi" "%%j")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to have relative path in `rename` argument. shouldn't it start with `C:/myFolder/` instead of just `myFolder/` ?

Comment: It's actually `C:/myFolder`, just needed to be more specific. Thanks for pointing that out but it's not what's causing the issue.

Comment: Is your second column just a filename or a full pathname? If the former, try `rename "C:/myFolder/%%~nxi" "C:/myFolder/%%j"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer used to contain my *wrong* suggestion from comments:

When the second column isn't a full pathname, but just a file name, `rename "C:/myFolder/%%~nxi" "%%j"` takes its destination argument as a path relative to *current* directory, not to the *source* directory.

I thought the problem should be solved by providing a full path name in the second argument of `rename` as well:

```
rename "C:/myFolder/%%~nxi" "C:/myFolder/%%j"
```

But no: the full path name is actually *invalid* in the destination argument for `rename`. The solution of `cd`ing to the target directory first and renaming without folder names in *either* argument turned out to work. I think that replacing forward slashes with backslashes in the *first* argument (leaving the *second* without the folder name) would help too: in my tests on Windows XP, `rename` failed with "file not found" when a source folder path contained forward slashes, and worked for backslashes.

Comment: My second column is a filename, I just tried adding the `c:/myFolder/%%j` and it didn't fix the issue. I wonder if I should do the renaming portion outside of this `For` loop, i.e. have another `For` loop for renaming after the copy/pasting `For` loop is fully executed.

Comment: Hmm. What if you temporary replace `rename` with `echo rename`, is the output what you expect? And if you copy-paste-run a line of the output (which should be a rename command), does it succeed or fail and what does it say? (It doesn't look like a separate `for` could help here)

Comment: `C:\>(copy "\\serverfiles\userapps\system\specfiles\205\558\584032.1" "C:/myFolder" && echo "C:/myFolder/584032.1" "C:/myFolder/New_Filename1" ) 1 file(s) copied. "C:/myFolder/584032.1" "C:/myFolder/New_Filename1"` It does display what I needed to see, but for some reason, the renaming is still not working. BTW, I tried it in a separate `For` loop and you're right, it did the same thing.

Comment: What if you try as you started (with rename and **no full path**), but use *backslashes* instead of *forward slashes* for the first argument of `rename`? On Windows XP here, rename fails when a directory is specified with `/`s, but works with `\\`s.

Comment: I actually did add a `cd "c:/myFolder"` between the copy and rename commands and it seems to be working now: `'For /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%i in (myCSV.csv) do (copy "%%i" "C:/myFolder" && cd "C:/myFolder" && rename %%~nxi %%j)'`. Thanks a lot for your help, Anton.